# Spheres without different points are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, spheres

I'm reading tom Dieck's book on algebraic topology. For a sphere $S^n$ and $N = e_{n + 1} = (0,...,0,1)$ (usually referred to as the *north pole*), he talks about a stereographic projection $\phi_N\colon S^n\setminus\{e_{n + 1}\} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $(x_1,...,x_n,x_{n + 1}) \mapsto \dfrac{1}{1 - x_{n + 1}}(x_1,...,x_n)$ and its inverse $\pi_N\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to S^n\setminus\{e_{n + 1}\}$ given by $(x_1,...,x_n) \mapsto \dfrac{1}{1 + |(x_1,...,x_n)|^2}(2x_1,...,2x_n, |(x_1,...,x_n)|^2 - 1)$.

There maps are mutually inverse homeomorphism.

But then tom Dieck tells that it follows from this that $S^n\setminus\{y\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for *any* $y \in S^n$. This means that there must be a reasonable homeomorphism $S^n\setminus\{x\}\to S^n\setminus\{y\}$ for $x \neq y$. I tried to build a more general homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ which maps $x$ to $y$, $y$ to $x$ and $z$ to itself for $z \neq x,y$, but it seems this map is not continuous, so one needs something more sophisticated.

Comment: Take a rotation mapping $x$ to $y$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Does there exists a reasonable parametrization of this map?

Comment: Good question how *explicit* we can describe rotations of $S^n$ (i.e. elements of the group $SO(n)$). I would do it as follows: Take a two-dimensional subspace $T$ of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ containing $x,y$ (if ($y \ne x,-x$, this is *uniquely determined*). Construct an orthonormal base $b_1,\ldots,b_{n+1}$ of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ such that $b_1,b_2$ span $T$. Then rotate $T$ such that $x$ is mapped to $y$. This rotation extends to an element of $SO(n)$ by keeping all $b_i$, $i > 2$, fixed. But I do not know a simple *universal formula* depending only on $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with the same length there's an isometry $f$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ taking $x$ to $y$. (One such is reflection in the hyperplane perpendicular to $x-y$.) In the case where both $x$ and $y$ have length $1$, the restriction of $f$ to $S^n \setminus\{x\}$ is a homeomorphism onto its image, which is $S^n\setminus\{y\}$.

Comment: Could you give a formula for such a map, please?

Comment: @Jxt921 It's a linear isometry, so it's more a matrix you're looking for. The formula is $x \to Ax$ for suitable $A$

Comment: @Jxt921 The reflection of $v$ in the hyperplane perpendicular to $a$ is given by $$ R(v) = v - 2\frac{v \cdot a}{a \cdot a}\, a $$